# Перегрузка потока

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь перегрузить `<<` для внутреннего класса

```
ostream& elem::operator<<(ostream& cout_, const elem& ob)
```

Возвращает ошибку:

> :: must be class or namespace name

Класс `elem` часть класса `set`.

в области описания

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const elem&){};
```

Весь код класса + код функции (да я знаю там есть говнокод, я исправляю сейчас):

```
class set{
public:
set():head(NULL),tail(NULL),size(0){};
set(int sz);       // конструктор по-умолчанию
set(const set &s); // копирующий конструктор

//отношения
set &operator =(const set &ob);                      //присваивание
int operator <(set &ob);                             //подмножество
int operator >(set &ob);                             //надмножество
int operator <(int el);                              //принадлежность элемента
int operator ==(set &ob);                            //эквивалентность
int operator !=(set &ob) {return !(*this==ob);}      //неэквивалентность

//операции над множествами
friend set operator +(int x, set &ob) {return ob+x;}
set operator +(int el) {add(el); return *this;}        //добавление элемента
set operator +(set &ob);                               //объединение множеств
set operator &(set &ob);                               //пересечение множеств
set operator -(set &ob);                               //разность
set operator -(int x);                                 //удаление элемента
set operator ^(set &ob);                               //симметрическая разность
set operator --(int x);                                //удаление элемента с конца
set operator --();                                     //удаление элемента из начала
int size() {return size;}                              //размер множества
friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const int&){};

private:
int size;                                              //размер множества

class elem{                                            //связанный список для хранения элементов множества
private:
    int data;
    elem* next;
public:
    friend class set;
    elem():next(NULL){};
    elem(int x):next(NULL),data(x){};
    void add(int x);                                   //добавление элемента в список+
    void del(int x);
    void clean();
    elem* find(int x);
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const elem&){}; 
};

elem *tail;                                            //хвост списка
elem *head;                                            //голова списка
};
```

код функции

```
ostream& set::elem::operator<<(ostream& cout_, const elem& ob)
{
cout_ << ob;
return cout_;
}
```

Comment: Где находится определение, в классе или отдельно?

Comment: определение отдельно

Comment: Приведите весь код. В данный момент складывается впечетление о неверной работе с областью видимости.

Comment: так это и ежу понятно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка здесь :

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const elem&){}; 
                                                   ^^ почему пустое тело ф-ции?
```

Comment: Да это косяк, но к конкретной ошибке не имеет отношения, уже убрал, все как было так и есть.

Comment: Тогда попробуйте поменять 
<pre>ostream& set::elem::operator<<(ostream& cout_, const elem& ob);</pre>
на
<pre>ostream& set::elem::operator<<(ostream& cout_, const set::elem& ob);</pre>

Comment: проблема похоже в параметрах. убрал все неймспейсы вроде нормально, а вот элем инаксесабл

Comment: Я тут подумал - а действительно, это логично. Этот оператор << получается не является ф-цией класса, а определяется снаружи, а затем уже утверждается, что он друг нашего вложенного класса, чтобы была возможность изменять его закрытые члены.
Т.е.
<pre>ostream& set::elem::operator<<(ostream& cout_, const elem& ob)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^ лишнее</pre>
А вот во втором аргументе наверняка namespace нужно указать, т.к. в глобальном namespace тоже может быть класс elem.

Comment: вот вот я добавил туда неймспейс от set и получилось именно elem is inaccessible, мне кажется надо как то дать стриму возможность посмотреть на это описание, но я что-то не могу сообразить как.

Comment: Поглядите <a href=http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/5843/>это</a>.
Гугль по c++ nested operator overloading должен выдать что-то вменяемое.
У меня, увы, нет компилятора под рукой, чтоб найти работающий вариант.

Comment: удалось решить путем вытаскивания класса элемента наружу, однако проблема все еще интересна

Comment: Либо второй вариант - сделать инлайновый оператор. Т.е. <pre>
friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const elem&){};
                                 сюда добавить код ^^^</pre>

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажеться, что ошибка в области видимости. Попробуйте что-то на вроде:

```
ostream& set::elem::operator<<(ostream& cout_, const elem& ob);
```

Comment: elem is inaccessible